# Redirect routes in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

I have 3 html files that I want to link together. The three files are `button.html`, `option1.html`, `option2.html` and all three files are stored in one src folder.

The `button.html` is a simple webpage that contains two buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("option1").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "./option1.html";
        };
        document.getElementById("option2").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "./option2.html";
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

      <button type="button" id="option1">Option 1</button>
      <button type="button" id="option2">Option 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and the two other .HTML file are regular pages each w/ different content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Option 1/2</title>
</head>
<body>

  // different data contained for option1.html and option2.html
  <h1>Heading for Option 1 or 2</h1>
  <p>Paragraph for Option 1 or 2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but even with the onClick() functions for each buttons, the buttons won't link to the other HTML files.
I'm wondering if I should have some kind of link tag in the header for the two HTML files. Also, I'm not very certain about that `location.href` line does in the script tag of `button.html` file. I just found some resources online to try this out.

Also, I need to do this using ONLY Vanila Javascript, HTML and CSS.

Please help me out. Thanks!!

Comment: Use n `<a>` tag with `href` instead of a `<button>`and you don't need any javascript at all

Comment: @charlietfl what if he likes buttons and doesn't want to go through the css of making a look like buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED :** This will work, I believe. See, first of all, always add your script tag just before the closing body tag. The reason is because that, the code will not work in case the DOM elements it looking for would not have been rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="option1">Option 1</button>
  <button type="button" id="option2">Option 2</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("option1").onclick = function() {
      location.href = "./option1.html";
    };
    document.getElementById("option2").onclick = function() {
      location.href = "./option2.html";
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no difference between window.location.href and location.href at all

Comment: @bluejayke yeah! I just realized that. Then maybe it is happening because the onclick method is being bind with undefined as the elements might not have been rendered till it gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need add the script tag before closing body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

      <button type="button" id="option1">Option 1</button>
      <button type="button" id="option2">Option 2</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("option1").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "./option1.html";
        };
        document.getElementById("option2").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "./option2.html";
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is this thing called a same origin policy  https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#can-t-get-but-can-set which  could be affected by location.href, if you are previewing the files in the local storage as opposed to a web server. Try changing it to location="./option.html" etc, removing the hrer

Alternatively you can make an invisible a tag, set the hrer, and click it with JS

var a=document.createElement("a");
a.href="option1.html";
a.click() ;

and put that in your onclick function instead,

EDIT another thing just realized

The script tags are in the head part of the html, but the buttons are in the body, so try copying the script tags to the bottom of the body tag, underneath the buttons, or surround both onclick functions with `window.onload=function {/*other code goes here*/}`

Comment: The only part of this that makes much sense is the last part. There is no cross origin issue here and nothing wrong with using `location.href` either

Comment: @charlietfl oh it's you again.. yes there potentially could be look at the link dude

Comment: You are imaging issues that don't exist in this situation. There is no problem navigating between pages in file protocol

Comment: @charlietfl never said it existed, just that it might potentially be a problem since as the article mentioned href could be treated as an xhr request